# How can I open and view an image file via an SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, image-viewers

### What I'm using

- Ubuntu 14.04
- SSH connection to another Ubuntu 14.04 machine

### What I'm trying to do

- View/Display the content of an image (`.png`, `.jpeg`, `.bmp`...) from the console.

I'm connecting to a VPS with Ubuntu and I need to know if an image file changes after I updated it, so I need to open/display the picture through ssh.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use GUI applications with `ssh`, you need to use the `-X` or `-Y` options (use `-Y`):

```
 -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
         basis in a configuration file.

         X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
         ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
         user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
         through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able
         to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.

         For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
         extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y
         option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for
         more information.
 -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
         subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

So, for example, to use `eog` to display the remote image at `/path/to/file.png`, you would do

```
ssh -Y liarez@remote.host eog /path/to/file.png
```